# PHP SQL Queries check if contains INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I allow userst to create SQL queries (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT) by posting a form.

The code:

```
$sql = $_POST["sql_query"]
mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

And I want to make a `mysqli_num_rows` if the `$sql` uses `SELECT`.

How to chek if the `$sql` contains an `SELECT`?

Comment: A SELECT seems like a different kind of thing to an INSERT or UPDATE to me. Surely that's relicated in your logic?

Comment: Allow users to construct their own queries ?

Comment: I am so sorry, my fault!!!

Comment: Yes, I am allowing users to construct queries.

Comment: I don't know the aim but for a security reason its seems crazy.

Comment: @Debflav I am developing an application for database management, like phpMyAdmin. I think it is not crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = '';
$rows = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if(strtoupper(substr($sql,0,6)) == 'SELECT')
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

`SELECT` will always be the first word in the SQL, so just compare the first six characters. Be sure to ignore case (I'm doing this by capitalising the letters) or you may miss some queries, but this should work as a quick and easy solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. +1 for first characters substr.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = $_POST["sql_query"];
if (strpos(strtolower($sql),'insert') !== false) 
{
    mysql_query($sql,$con);
}
else if (strpos(strtolower($sql),'select') !== false) 
{
  $row= mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql,$con));
}

[EDIT I dont know mysqli so i may not know the actual syntaxes. So i am giving w.r.t mysql]
```

Hope you can adjust it according to your convenience. Its the logic u need.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strstr($sql,'SELECT') || strstr($sql,'select')) {
    //your code here
    $query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    echo $count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When posting code, please also include a short explanation, so that the OP can understand the code.